# wpf disable tab navigation on text inside button

Tags: wpf, tabs, navigation

I have the following two buttons:

1. Button1



   Button2
2. Button2

In case of button1 the stackpannel inside gets focused.
In case of button2, the ContentText gets focused when navigating with tab.

I'm trying to disable tab navigation for the content inside the buttons, but without success.
I've have try each of:
    KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
    FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"

But none of them helped me.

UPDATE:
I've included the code in the first post but it doesn't appear. Sorry, I'm very new to stack.

Button1

```
<Button Command="{Binding Button1Command}">
<StackPanel>
<Image Source="button1.png"/>
<TextBlock>Button2</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Button2

```
<Button Command="{Binding Button2Command}" Content="{Binding Button2Text}"/>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code in the question? It'll make it easier for us to give you a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want buttons to be part of Tab navigation cycle of your window, set `Focusable to False` on your button.

```
<Button Focusable="False"/>
```

Comment: The button should be focusable. I press tab and the button gets focused, that's cool. If I press tab again the focus moves to the text inside the button... This is the behaviour I want to get rid of.

Comment: With this declaration `<Button Command="{Binding Button2Command}" Content="{Binding Button2Text}"/>` focus moves only to button, not to text.